# Designing a 8 bit ALU

Tags: digital-logic, microprocessor, alu

I have started designing a 4 bit Arithmetic and logic unit.

The sample image is as follows:

[image]

The function Table:

[image]

My question is: Is it possible to design an 8 bit ALU having the same functionalities (as in Table ), by using exactly two 4 bit ALU’s (as if Figure ) and an ‘And’ gate.?

Comment: I am not sure. Just thought an idea of making a 8 bit ALU. That's why asking. What's the main problem in doing so? @Eugene Sh

Comment: Actually wait...Sorry, it seems to be possible. Why do you need an AND gate?

Comment: All of the functions will work if you just parallelize the ALUs, except the addition, where you just need to chain the carry. **Update:** Ah, perhaps the AND gate is to combine the zero flag.

Comment: If you want a full explanation, you better ask a new question (or change this one significantly), conforming the rules.

Comment: Note that you are performing two additions in operations 2 and 3 and doubling the number of bits from 4 to 8. Doing both of these will require 4 4-bit ALUs, two per operation.

Comment: @AndrewW. It's an addition with single-bit carry-in. Only two 4-bit full adders required.

Comment: Ok, so now we have the answer. But I wonder how OP knew he would need an AND gate without knowing the answer... Oh, wait... Amazing the amount of homework questions these times.

Comment: yeah, i'm getting down there.  you should delete your first comment, me thinkgs.  i am deleting my second comment.  maybe both of them.

Answer (score 2):

What you show is similar to the old AMD 2901 4-bit "bit-slice" ALU chip. You should be able to cascade them to any length, but longer equals slower because of the carry chain. You will need an AND gate to combine the "zero" flags. You can take the "carry", "sign" and "overflow" flags from the most-significant chip.

To cascade them, you simply need to tie the "carry-out" of the lesser significant 4 bits to the "carry-in" of the next higher 4 bits. Be sure to tie the lowest order "carry-in" to something you can control (one of your instruction bits) because it needs to be a 0 for an ADD, and a 1 for an INCREMENT or a SUBTRACT.

Wikipedia link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD_Am2900

Answer (score -1):

Your question is not well formulated, since you have not specified your arithmetic format. The logical functions can all be done with 2 chips. You don't even need to connect the two except for the function.

Your first arithmetic function is simple, and simply connecting the lower carry out to the upper carry in will work fine, as long as you're adding unsigned binary. 2's complement won't work, though.

However, the second function is a bit odd. Why would you want to add the complements? To produce subtraction? Won't work for 2's complement. Won't work for 1's complement either. In either format, think what subtracting zero does.

Without knowing what that function means to you, I'd have to say no.

Comment: Actually, 2's compliment will work. It not intuitive that it would, but the "sign" bit of the lower 4 bits will behave correctly for 2's compliment, as an ordinary bit. The "carry" from the low 4 bits can be used as a "half-carry" for BCD arithmetic. The second function will work correctly as a subtract if you set the lowest "carry-in" to a one (changing the "compliment" to a "compliment and increment", the 2's compliment definition of negation).