# Compare numbers using flag registers

Tags: digital-logic, microprocessor

Suppose I have a four bit number. How Will I check whether the number is greater than or equal to zero logically by using flag registers?

I can check if the number is equal to zero or not by Or ing with 0000 and checking the zero flag . But what about the other case?

Comment: The question is not clear - you need to deconflict 'greater than or equal to'. If a binary number is not zero it must be greater than zero, unless you are using complement arithmetic.

Comment: @Chu - You can't tell from this question alone, but it appears that he is using 2's compliment arithmetic, based on his other question here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/237474/designing-a-8-bit-alu

Answer (score 1):

You would use combinations of flags. Specifically, the ZERO flag and the SIGN flag. Here's a truth table:

```
 zero        ZERO
 > zero      NOT-ZERO  and  NOT-SIGN
 < zero      NOT-ZERO  and  SIGN
 >= zero     ZERO      or   NOT-SIGN
 <= zero     ZERO      or   SIGN
```

So you would OR the ZERO flag with the compliment of the SIGN flag.

Comment: can you please explain how the table has been constructed? @Mark